# Flow of execution in word2vec tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing, word2vec

From past few days, I have been trying to figure out the flow of execution in the code https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py#L28  .

I understood the logic behind negative sampling and loss function, but I am getting so confused about the flow of execution inside the train function, especially when it comes to `_train_thread_body` function. I am so confused about the while and if loops ( what is the impact ) and the concurrency related parts. It would be great, if someone can give a decent explanation, before down-voting this.

Answer (score 1):

This [sample code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py) is called "*Multi-threaded* word2vec mini-batched skip-gram model", that's why it uses several independent threads for training. Word2Vec can be trained with a single thread as well, but this tutorial shows that word2vec is faster to compute when done in parallel.

The input, label and epoch tensors are provided by the native `word2vec.skipgram_word2vec` function, which is implemented in [`tutorials/embedding/word2vec_kernels.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec_kernels.cc#L51) file. There you can see that `current_epoch` is a tensor updated once the whole corpus of sentences is processed.

The method you're asking about is actually pretty simple:

```py
def _train_thread_body(self):
  initial_epoch, = self._session.run([self._epoch])
  while True:
    _, epoch = self._session.run([self._train, self._epoch])
    if epoch != initial_epoch:
      break
```

First, it computes the current epoch, then it invokes the training until the `epoch` is increased. This means that all of threads running this method will make *exactly one* epoch of training. Each thread is doing one step at a time in parallel with others.

`self._train` is an op that optimizes the loss function (see `optimize` method), which is computed from current `examples` and `labels` (see `build_graph` method). The exact value of these tensors is in native code again, namely in `NextExample`. Essentially, each call of `word2vec.skipgram_word2vec` extracts the set of examples and labels, which form the input to the optimization function. Hope, it makes it clearer now.

By the way, this model uses [NCE loss](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/13216/18375) in training, not negative sampling.